# Java - Converting String to JSON object issue

Tags: java, json, string

I imported the JSON library

`import org.json.JSONObject;`

I have the string `sb`

```
sb = {"contentPackages":{"name":"abc","url":"some-url","title":"Annotated Examples","description":"something"}};

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb);
System.out.println(jsonObj);
```

I get a blank object `{}` as output. I have no idea why.

Comment: what is sb? a `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Your String should look like this:

```
sb = "{\"contentPackages\":{\"name\":\"abc\",\"url\":\"some-url\",\"title\":\"Annotated Examples\",\"description\":\"something\"}}";
```

Don't forget that every String starts and ends with `"` character. If you want store it as the character itself, you have to use `\"`.